# How to properly dereference all addresses of a pointer in Cython?

Tags: numpy, pointers, malloc, cython, dereference

I'm learning the basics of Cython 3.0 and I'm trying to understand why one of my approaches to dereferencing a pointer (to multiple memory addresses) in order to initialize the values in those addresses doesn't work while the other approaches do work.

Here is my test code

```
import numpy as np
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc

np_arr = np.array([1.0, 2.0])

cdef double[2] c_arr1 = [1.0, 2.0] # this works

cdef double[2] c_arr2 = np_arr.tolist() # this works

cdef double *c_arr3 = <double *>malloc(2*sizeof(double))
c_arr3[:] = [1.0, 2.0] # this works

cdef double *c_arr4 = <double *>malloc(2*sizeof(double))
c_arr4[:] = np_arr.tolist() # this doesn't work; gives two compile errors

cdef double *c_arr5 = <double *>malloc(2*sizeof(double))
c_arr5[0] = np_arr.tolist()[0]
c_arr5[1] = np_arr.tolist()[1] # this works
```

The compile errors for `c_arr4` are: "Cannot convert Python object to 'double *'" and "Storing unsafe C derivative of temporary Python reference".

It seems that using `[:]` on a pointer doesn't actually dereference all of the addresses, yet `c_arr3` managed to initialize with it. So my questions are:

1. Why does `c_arr3[:] = [1.0, 2.0]` work? What is the `[:]` doing exactly?
2. If `c_arr3[:]` and `c_arr4[:]` are considered as `double *` objects to Cython, why is `np_arr.tolist()` considered a Python object but not `[1.0, 2.0]`?
3. Is there another (ideally more efficient) way of changing the values at the addresses of a pointer without manually looping through each address like I did for `c_arr5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let's have a look at your Cython code

```py
cdef double *c_arr3 = <double *>malloc(2*sizeof(double))
c_arr3[:] = [1.0, 2.0]
```

Here, the python list `[1.0, 2.0]` is only meant to initialise the block of memory on the heap your pointer `c_arr3` points to. Therefore, there's no need to create a python list from a performance perspective. That's one of the reasons why Cython will roughly generate the following C code instead:

```c
/* allocate the memory */
double* c_arr3 = (double*) malloc(2*sizeof(double));

/* create a C array (instead of a list) to initialize c_arr3 */
double tmp[2];
tmp[0] = 1.0;
tmp[1] = 2.0;

/* copy all values of tmp into c_arr3 */
memcpy(&c_arr3[0], &tmp[0], 2*sizeof(double));
```

The `a[:] = expr` is Cython's slicing syntax that is typically used for typed memoryviews and works pretty similar to numpy arrays. Thus, it's mainly used to copy values of the right-hand-side `expr` into `a`.

2. `c_arr3[:]`and `c_arr4[:]` are no `double*`. It's just syntactic sugar  in Cython for copying values (see the above C code), which also means that it can be used to initialize blocks of memory. However, at the time of writing, initialization via `c_arr3[:] = expr` only works for simple right-hand side *literals* like python lists.
3. Yes, you could use a [typed memoryview](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) instead of raw pointers:

```
cdef double[::1] c_mv = <double[:2]>malloc(2*sizeof(double))

# set all values to 1.0
c_mv[:] = 1.0

# initialize it with the values of np_arr
# note that you don't need to convert np_arr to a list
c_mv[:] = np_arr[:]

# don't forget to free the memory!
free(&c_mv[0])
```